# Pandas replace values

Tags: python, replace, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
     col
0    pre
1    post
2    a
3    b
4    post
5    pre
6    pre
```

I want to replace all rows in the dataframe which do not contain 'pre' to become 'nonpre', so dataframe looks like:

```
     col
0    pre
1    nonpre
2    nonpre
3    nonpre
4    nonpre
5    pre
6    pre
```

I can do this using a dictionary and pandas replace, however I want to just select the elements which are not 'pre' and replace them with 'nonpre'. is there a better way to do that without listing all possible col values in a dictionary?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As long as you're comfortable with the `df.loc[condition, column]` syntax that pandas allows, this is very easy, just do `df['col'] != 'pre'` to find all rows that should be changed:

```
df['col2'] = df['col']
df.loc[df['col'] != 'pre', 'col2'] = 'nonpre'

df
Out[7]: 
    col    col2
0   pre     pre
1  post  nonpre
2     a  nonpre
3     b  nonpre
4  post  nonpre
5   pre     pre
6   pre     pre
```

Comment: thanks! is there any issue with using .loc I should be wary of?

Comment: No, `.loc` is basically what you should be trying first when you want to get at a particular set of rows and columns in your dataframe. Not sure if you have experience with R, but it works very similarly to the subsetting syntax for R dataframes.

Answer (score 6):

```
df[df['col'].apply(lambda x: 'pre' not in x)] = 'nonpre'
```