# Pandas replacing values on specific columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am aware of these two similar questions:

[Pandas replace values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27117773/pandas-replace-values)

[Pandas: Replacing column values in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23307301/pandas-replacing-column-values-in-dataframe)

I used a different approach for substituting values from which I think it should be the cleanest one. But it does not work. I know how to work around it, but I would like to understand why it does not work:

```
In [108]: df=pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 8],[3, 4, 8], [5, 1, 8]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C']) 

In [109]: df
Out[109]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  2  8
1  3  4  8
2  5  1  8

In [110]: df.loc[:, ['A', 'B']].replace([1, 3, 2], [3, 6, 7], inplace=True)

In [111]: df
Out[111]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  2  8
1  3  4  8
2  5  1  8

In [112]: df.loc[:, 'A'].replace([1, 3, 2], [3, 6, 7], inplace=True)

In [113]: df
Out[113]: 
   A  B  C
0  3  2  8
1  6  4  8
2  5  1  8
```

If I slice only one column `In [112]` it works different to slicing several columns `In [110]`. As I understand the `.loc` method it returns a view and not a copy. In my logic this means that making an inplace change on the slice should change the whole DataFrame. This is what happens at line `In [110]`.

Comment: you have a typo in your df ctor, you need to pass `columns=['A','B','C']`

Comment: I think this is because your syntax is wrong: `df.loc[:, 'A': 'B'].replace([1, 3, 2], [3, 6, 7], inplace=True)` works, it seems to raise a `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
` warning for some reason

Comment: Actually I think this is a bug now, it should work as `df.loc[:, 'A': 'B'].replace` is the same as `df.loc[:, ['A', 'B']].replace`

Comment: Thank you very much! Since I want to apply this on several columns that are separated your slicing solution does not work for me. I will use `df.loc[:, ['A', 'B']] = df.loc[:, ['A', 'B']].replace([1, 3, 2], [3, 6, 7])` and write this to pandas bug report.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here is the answer by one of the developers: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11984

> This should ideally show a SettingWithCopyWarning, but I think this is
> quite difficult to detect.
>
> You should NEVER do this type of chained inplace setting. It is simply
> bad practice.
>
> idiomatic is:
>
> ```
> In [7]: df[['A','B']] = df[['A','B']].replace([1, 3, 2], [3, 6, 7])
>
> In [8]: df
> Out[8]: 
>    A  B  C
> 0  3  7  8
> 1  6  4  8
> 2  5  3  8
> ```
>
> (you can do with `df.loc[:,['A','B']]` as well, but more clear as above.

Answer (score 3):

```
to_rep = dict(zip([1, 3, 2],[3, 6, 7]))
df.replace({'A':to_rep, 'B':to_rep}, inplace = True)
```

This will return:

```
   A  B  C
0  3  7  8
1  6  4  8
2  5  3  8
```