# Replacing values in multiple specific columns of a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

raw_data = {
    'Score1': [42, 52, -999, 24, 73], 
    'Score2': [-999, -999, -999, 2, 1],
    'Score3': [2, 2, -999, 2, -999]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Score1', 'Score2', 'Score3'])
```

and I want to replace the -999's with NaN only in columns Score2 and Score3, leaving column Score1 unchanged. I want to reference the columns to be modified by name and they might not be consecutive.

I have tried things like:

```
df.loc[:,('Score2', 'Score3')].replace(-999, np.nan, inplace=True)
df
```

but this does not work, I assume because it is operating on the copy. Is there a way of doing this in one statement?

I looked at [Pandas replacing values on specific columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653215/pandas-replacing-values-on-specific-columns) but found it quite confusing, so felt a simpler example would help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas replacing values on specific columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653215/pandas-replacing-values-on-specific-columns)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannnot use `inplace=True`, because subset returns a Series which may have its data as a view. Modifying it in place doesn't ALWAYS propogate it back to the parent object. That's why `SettingWithCopyWarning` is possible there (or raise if you set the option). You should never do this, nor is their ever a reason to do so.

```
df[['Score2', 'Score3']] = df[['Score2', 'Score3']].replace(-999, np.nan)
print (df)
   Score1  Score2  Score3
0      42     NaN     2.0
1      52     NaN     2.0
2    -999     NaN     NaN
3      24     2.0     2.0
4      73     1.0     NaN
```

Comment: Thanks. Both solutions work but I am accepting this answer because it is more intuitive to me and doesn't require 'inplace=True'.

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
In [282]: df.replace({'Score2': -999, 'Score3': -999}, np.nan)
Out[282]:
   Score1  Score2  Score3
0      42     NaN     2.0
1      52     NaN     2.0
2    -999     NaN     NaN
3      24     2.0     2.0
4      73     1.0     NaN
```