# Replace string in dataframe if a condition in a different row is met

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe made up of a date and a value column, kind of like this:

```
>>> df
         date   value
0  2016-09-10  value1
1  2016-09-10  value1
2  2016-09-10  value2
3  2016-09-10  value1
4  2016-09-12  value3
5  2016-09-12  value1
6  2016-09-13  value2
7  2016-09-13  value1
```

I would like to replace all of the `value1` in `df['value']` that fall on the date '2016-09-10' with `value7`. The Date column is a string series.

I looked at the documentation for `pd.DataFrame.replace()`, but couldn't find an argument for a conditional replace based on a separate column. Plenty of ugly ways to get this done jump to mind (`for` loops with `.loc` would do the trick), but does anyone know a nice, one-or-two line, and more pythonic way to do this? Thanks in advance!

#### If you want this mini-dummy-dataframe to experiment with:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'date': ['2016-09-10', '2016-09-10',
                 '2016-09-10', '2016-09-10',
                 '2016-09-12', '2016-09-12',
                 '2016-09-13', '2016-09-13'],
        'value': ['value1', 'value1', 'value2', 'value1',
                  'value3', 'value1', 'value2', 'value1']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about

```
>> df.loc[(df['date'] == '2016-09-10') & (df['value'] == 'value1'), 'value'] = 'value7'
```

You may want to read [Indexing and Selecting Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) section and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27117773/pandas-replace-values#27117982) for more info

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep everything else same and change what you need, try this,

```
df.loc[df['date'] == '2016-09-10' , 'value'] = 'value7'
```