# Problem Running OLS with Stata Data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, stata

I am having problems running OLS in Python after reading in Stata data. Below are my codes and error message

```
import pandas as pd  # To read data
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

gss = pd.read_stata("gssSample.dta", preserve_dtypes=False)
X = gss[['age', 'impinc' ]]
y = gss[['educ']]
X = sm.add_constant(X) # adding a constant
model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
print(model.summary())
```

The error message says:

```
ValueError: Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input data with np.asarray(data).
```

So any thoughts how to run this simple OLS?

Comment: Can you share a small example of the data?

Comment: Certainly. You can download the data file [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f5Ofs0LuwzNroToLM16sRdZsGj1qwCGW/view?usp=sharing) and reproduce the results using my codes above.

Comment: Please post data in body of question to avoid dead or forbidden links for current and future readers.

Comment: So no link in the comment, but link in the body of my question?

Comment: Yes, this is what @Parfait is asking. It is important to pick a set of observations that reproduces your problem. The community has produced some guidance for this process [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 4):

Your `age` variable contains a value `"89 or older"` which is causing it to be read as a string, which is not a valid input for `statsmodels`. You have to deal with this so it can be read as integer or float, for example like this:

```py
gss = pd.read_stata("gssSample.dta", preserve_dtypes=False)
gss = gss[gss.age != '89 or older']
gss['age'] = gss.age.astype(float)
X = gss[['age', 'impinc' ]]
y = gss[['educ']]
X = sm.add_constant(X) # adding a constant
model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
print(model.summary())
```

P.S. I'm not saying that dropping observations where `age == "89 or older"` is the best way. You'll have to decide how best to deal with this. If you want to have a categorical variable in your model you'll have to create dummies first.

EDIT: If your .dta file contains a numeric value with value labels, the value labels will be used as values by default causing it to be read as string. You can use `convert_categoricals=False` with `pd.read_stata` to read in the numeric values.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help here. I am kind of confused. The issue is '89 or older is coded as 89' in Stata. 89 or older is the value lable. So after I use read_stata to read the Stata data into python, 89 with that label would become a string? Is there anyway to read in the age variable as numeric (e.g., any option in the read_stata)? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If a .dta file contains a variable with value labels, `pandas.read_stata` takes the value labels as the values for the DataFrame by default, see [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_stata.html). You can add the `convert_categoricals=False` option to read in the numeric values, which in this case actually appears to be a better solution. I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: Adding `convert_categoricals=False` made it work! Fantastic! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative second line of @Wouter's solution could be:

```py
gss.loc[gss.age=='89 or older','age']='89'
```

See this [discussion of replacing based on a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47933535/replace-string-in-dataframe-if-a-condition-in-a-different-row-is-met) for more details.

Of course, whether this replacement is appropriate depends on your use case.

Comment: Note that Wouter's question completely addresses the question you asked in the original post. I'd encourage you to mark that as the accepted answer.